# Pickle cross platform __dict__ attribute error

Tags: python, cross-platform, pickle

I'm having an issue with pickle. Things work fine between OSX and Linux, but not Windows and Linux. All pickled strings are stored in memory and sent via an SSL socket. To be 100% clear I have replaced all '\n's with ":::" and all '\r's with "===" (there were none). Scenario:

- Client-Win: Small Business Server 2011 running Python 2.7
- Client-Lin: Fedora Linux running Python 2.7
- Server: Fedora Linux running Python 2.7

Client-Lin sends a pickled object to Server:

`ccopy_reg:::_reconstructor:::p0:::(c__main__:::infoCollection:::p1:::c__builtin__:::tuple:::p2:::(VSTRINGA:::p3:::VSTRINGB:::p4:::VSTRINGC:::p5:::tp6:::tp7:::Rp8:::.`

Client-Win sends a picked object to Server:

`ccopy_reg:::_reconstructor:::p0:::(c__main__:::infoCollection:::p1:::c__builtin__:::tuple:::p2:::(VSTRINGA:::p3:::VSTRINGB:::p4:::VSTRINGC:::p5:::tp6:::tp7:::Rp8:::ccollections:::OrderedDict:::p9:::((lp10:::(lp11:::S'string_a':::p12:::ag3:::aa(lp13:::S'string_b':::p14:::ag4:::aa(lp15:::S'string_c':::p16:::ag5:::aatp17:::Rp18:::b.`

For some reason the Windows client sends extra information along with the pickle, and when the Linux client tries to load the pickle string I get:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function TestThread at 0x107de60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 212, in TestThread
    info = pickle.loads(p_string)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1224, in load_build
    d = inst.__dict__
AttributeError: 'infoCollection' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

Any ideas?

***EDIT***
Adding additional requested information.

The infoCollection class is defined the same way:

```
infoCollection = collections.namedtuple('infoCollection', 'string_a, string_b, string_c')

def runtest():
    info = infoCollection('STRINGA', 'STRINGB', 'STRINGC')
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(s, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    ssl_sock.connect((server, serverport))
    ssl_sock.write(pickle.dumps(info))
    ssl_sock.close()
```

And the receiving function is much the same but does a

```
p_string = ssl_sock.read()
info = pickle.loads(p_string)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can show us the code that does the pickling, and the data that goes into it?

Comment: Is the class `infoCollection` defined exactly the same in both environments?

Comment: Just updated the post with additional information.

Comment: could you post the output if you use pickle with protocol version 0 (more readable) `dumps(string, 0)`

Comment: 0 is the default protocol. Tried it just in case and it outputs the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hack, but the cross-platform issue appears to be due to namedtuples and pickle together in a cross-platform environment. I have replaced the namedtuple with my own class and all works well.

```
class infoClass(object):
    pass

def infoCollection(string_a, string_b, string_c):
    i = infoClass()
    i.string_a = string_a
    i.string_b = string_b
    i.string_c = string_c
    return i
```

Comment: If someone solves the namedtuple/pickle combination error. I will happily mark that as a more formal answer.

Comment: The problem is the reconstuctor function, I think. I would prefer your solution over fixing the code of others.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using different minor versions of Python? There's a bug in 2.7.3 that makes pickling namedtuples incompatible with older versions. See this:

http://ronrothman.com/public/leftbraned/python-2-7-3-bug-broke-my-namedtuple-unpickling/

Comment: Welcome!  For future reference, leave a comment under the question asking for clarification.  Then answer when you have the information you need.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I should have worded the answer differently? Maybe something like: "This issue is usually caused by..."?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving as a binary pickle file?

```
with open('pickle.file', 'wb') as po:
    pickle.dump(obj, po)
```

Also - if you're porting between various OS, and if `info` is just a `namedtuple` have you looked at [JSON](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) (it's generally considered safer than `pickle`)?

```
with open('pickle.json', 'w') as po:
    json.dump(obj, po)
```

**Edit**
From the `ssl` `.read()` [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ssl.html#sslsocket-objects) it seems that `.read()` will only read at most 1024 bytes by default, I'll wager that your `info` namedtuple is going to be larger than that. It would be difficult to know how big `info` is *a-priori* I don't know if just setting `nbytes=HUGE NUMBER` would do the trick (I think perhaps not).

Comment: I have thought about JSON, but JSON does not offer the ease of transitioning an object. I.E. with pickle I can access "info.STRINGA" without having to redefine things every time I load the string. Also, I can't use pickle binary easily, as I'm sending from memory over the socket.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you

```
p_string = ssl_sock.read(nbytes=1.0E6)
info = pickle.loads(p_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just install Pyhton 2.7.8 from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/python-2.7.8.amd64.msi