# Can't unpickle old data

Tags: python, pickle

I got a program I haven't used in a long time, and it has info stored in the pickle format. I want to get this info out. I tried to run this program now, but I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'class_info_image_one' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

`class_info_image_one` is a namedtuple.

Found this referenced here: [Pickle cross platform __dict__ attribute error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959495/python-pickle-scross-platform-dict-attribute-error)

So, on which version of python this program should run? I tried python 3.7 and python 3.1, same error on both.

Tried with python 2.7, got this error:

```
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
```

This is the code I'm using, I removed everything that isn't necessary:

```
import os
import pickle

from collections import deque, namedtuple


class_info_image_one = namedtuple('class_info_image_one', 'md5 extension id tags rating source has_notes has_sample parent_id has_children created_at status author creator_id width height file_size has_comments score')


if os.path.isfile('info_image.pickle'):
    with open('info_image.pickle', 'rb') as lolfile:
        info_image = pickle.load( lolfile )
```

Comment: On which version of python should _what_ run? There's no code in your question. What's making the file? What's reading the file? What versions of Python were these running?

Comment: When you pickle something you need to pick a "protocol" that earlier versions of Python will understand. Later versions can usually read earlier versions (although probably not from one with bugs), but not vice versa.

Comment: It was pickled 6 years ago, too late to think about that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the discussion on the Python bug you linked, the broken `__dict__` in the pickle existed in Python 3.2 and 3.3, and was fixed in 3.3.2.  Apparently it didn’t prevent unpickling in the same version.

Comment: Version 3.3.2 worked. Strange that this bug reappeared in 3.7.2. Installed that version from the site, used `py -3.2 myprogram.py`, and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: @woopwoop399: 3.7.2 doesn’t have a bug: those few earlier versions are just incompatible with (many) other versions.